# SQL find rows in different tables using the same ID

Tags: postgresql

I have tableA containing a column called user_id AND another column called flag_count
I need to filter all the rows in tableA with a flag_count=12 and then use the user_id in those rows to query tableB and return all the rows using the same user_id AND said rows also contain a column value of registered=true

This is what I have so far:

```
select * from public.tableA where user_id in (
    select user_id from public.tableB
    where flag_count = 12
    group by user_id having count(*) = 1
)
and registered='true'
```

This looks straight forward enough but I cannot find a simple solution.
Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Change that last `and` to `WHERE` and rerun.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "where"

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data for your two tables?

Comment: Apologies. I got busy with a meeting. The subquery simply needs an alias. `AS dt` after that last parentheses and you should be in business. The take-away is that your query was very close to working as you intended. You just had a couple of syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have it work more efficiently by using a `JOIN` operation and adding a index on "*public.tableA.user_id*".

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT user_id 
    FROM public.tableB
    WHERE flag_count = 12
    GROUP BY user_id 
    HAVING count(*) = 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM       public.tableA a
INNER JOIN cte
        ON a.user_id = cte.user_id AND a.registered = 'true'
```

Subquery *may* be further simplified, though it depends on the kind of data you have. Having sample data could help for that.